# ACF User fileld for subscriber not return value

Tags: wordpress, advanced-custom-fields

I'm using WordPress ACF plugin to store users' data.

The values I'm calling in template are as below:

```
echo $uid=get_current_user_id();
echo $lesson_order = get_field('lesson_order', 'user_'.$uid);
echo $last_lesson_time = get_field('last_lesson_time', "user_".$uid);
```

The values returned for admins are correct, but when logged in as a subscriber, the code returns empty values. I also checked user ids, which appear to be correct.

Can someone give me a solution to this. Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 1):

I've tested both option on a local project and both were working but have you tried retrieving the user ID using this instead?

```
<?php
   $current_user = wp_get_current_user();
   echo "Current User ID " . $current_user->ID;
?>
```

If it still doesn't work, can you show a little more of your code?

You can also check that answer for more information : https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/163407/get-current-user-id-returns-0